# Need hex value in list to be treated as int to calculate with bin(). What am I missing?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Short backstory:

I am currently working on a key serial number (KSN) converter written in Python. It uses a tkinter framework I wrote to input the values to be converted. Basically, put a serial number in the box, press convert, output KSN. Super simple and it works. However, the serial numbers I've been receiving lately are becoming alphanumeric, which my converter does not support.

Issue:

I need to be able to take serial numbers within a list, both numerical and alphanumerical, change the alphanumerical values to hexadecimal, and be able to calculate each value in the list into binary values. However when calculating,  I receive

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: (hex value)
```

I have already tried googling for a solution, and I've checked other answers on stack overflow, but they don't seem to provide the solution I'm looking for. I've tried making a function to convert the data, I've tried to break down the process in to more drawn out processes to see the break point, but everything comes back down to, my hex value is considered a string. I know `bin()` can calculate something like `0x123abc` but it obviously wont take `'0x123abc'` which is the problem.

```
serial_box = ['201805138', '239487D9298', '201805138', '239487D9298']

stage =  [hex(int(x, 16)) if x.isdigit() is False else x for x in serial_box]
stage2 = [bin(int(x.strip())) for x in stage]

print stage
print stage2
```

Output:

```
    stage2 = [bin(int(x.strip())) for x in stage]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x239487d9298L'
```

The first stage variable should return the list in serial_box as:

```
['201805138', '0x239487d9298L', '201805138', '0x239487d9298L']
```

stage2 needs to return the list values as:

```
['0b1100000001110100110101010010', '0b100011100101001000011111011001001010011000', '0b1100000001110100110101010010', '0b100011100101001000011111011001001010011000']
```

Comment: Side note: do not use `x.isdigit() is False`; just use `not x.isdigit()`.

Comment: Another side note: Python 2 is [reaching it's end of life in 8 months time](https://pythonclock.org/). If this is a new project, I *strongly* recommend you switch to Python 3 as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you, and I'm well aware that Python2 is about to EOL. I've informed my company months ago, and we are slowly converting the database over to 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `int(..., 16)` on a string that contains *more* than just the hexadecimal digits (0-9, a-f), and an optional `0x` prefix. Your input string has a trailing `L` (for a long integer).

The trailing `L` needs to be removed:

```
>>> int('0x239487d9298L', 16)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '0x239487d9298L'
>>> int('0x239487d9298', 16)
2445052580504
```

If you can't prevent the inputs from sometimes containing a trailing `L`, just use `str.rstrip('L')` to remove them.

Personally, I'd keep all the data as integers, and only format those integer values as strings (binary or hexadecimal or otherwise) when needed for display purposes.

This produces a list of integer values from a mix of base-10 and base-16 strings:

```
int_values = [int(v.rstrip('L'), 16 if v[:2] == '0x' else 10) for v in serial_box]
```

Comment: Noted, I'll use this information and see what I can do with it, then report back if I can get this to work. 

As an aside, the data has to start out as strings in a list due to the input. The program will have a GUI with a text box, and will allow multiple lines of data to be input into a list. That's a hard requirement from my superior, unfortunately.

Comment: Also as a clarification, I do not need to calculate the hex number using int(), but using bin()

I am able to calculate bin(0x239487D298L) and receive the same output without the L. Regardless, I could still slice the L off, no problem. I just need the hex value to not be a string so bin() can calculate it.

Comment: @geurillapaint: that doesn't mean you can't store integers in your app. The UI textbox lets the user provide values for your internal state, it should not itself be the storage for the state.

Comment: @geurillapaint: but `0x239487D298L` is not a string. It's just another way of spelling out an integer value in Python code, so it's an [*integer literal*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals). While you could use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert strings with Python literal notation to Python objects, if all you need to accept is integers I'd limit the UI to only accept valid integer numbers in a limited number of formats.

Comment: I've not used Tkinter before this project, so I was not aware of this. I'll do more research in to that matter.

Comment: @geurillapaint: Tkinter is no different from other GUIs or input methods (web forms, command-line options, data received from a network connection or file); it's just another form of input provided to your program. It's always best to convert string input to an efficient data type to operate on as soon as possible, so at the point of input, and delay converting back to a representation (string, graph, whatever) as long as possible. Here, that's strings from a textbox, and integers as the efficient data type.

Comment: Thank you for your time, and I appreciate you going over this with me. It looks like implementing ast.literal_eval in to my code gets me the results I was looking for.